# How to make jQuery show Loading picture while doing a function?

Tags: jquery

How to make jQuery show Loading picture while doing a function?

Comment: Depends what the ... is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are performing some asynchronous operation. Perhaps $.ajax? Here is a code snippet:

```
$('<div class="loading">loading ... </div>').appendTo(document.body);
$.ajax({ 
 url: "...",
 complete: function () {
    $("div.loading").remove();
 },
 success: function() {
   //....
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to block the UI while ajax calls are running.  You should take a look at [jQuery BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).  I have used it in a mobile app and it works well.  You can add text and gif images to customize the blocking screen.